# How To Compile And Run C++ Projects On xCode Macbook

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, debugging

I've just accepted the fact that VScode will not work w/ C++, so I'm going to go with Xcode as my IDE...
However, it's no longer as simple as opening the related main.cpp file + related header files and running the code...because if I'm correct xcode cannot actually 'run the code' unless I open all the files through 'project_name.xcodeproj'.
Is there a fast and easy way for me to go through each c++ project folder I have and turn them into .xcodeproj's that open all those files and allow me to run/debug?

Comment: ***I've just accepted the fact that VScode will not work w/ C++*** It can be made to work but it is more difficult if you have more than 1 source file per executable. The instructions at the vscode site tell you how to modify your `tasks.json` to handle that. With this said unless you are an advanced user who understands their compiler VSCode will be more difficult for you.

Comment: C++ will work with VS Code, but you have to read a few how-to and tutorial pages (Really, you only need one good one, but odds are you won't Google up that good one first time out). And you either A) already know what you're doing or B) follow the instructions exactly.

Comment: No C++ environment or toolset simply "runs the code" - it's a compiled language, so you have to tell the compiler which files to compile (and where to find header files and any library dependencies), compile and link, and if the output is an executable you can run/debug that. If your project is pretty self contained, just creating a new Xcode project with appropriate target (e.g. CLI tool, C++ language) and adding your files to it is pretty quick. If you google "learning C++ with Xcode" you'll find plenty of tutorials, e.g. https://medium.com/@VIRAL/mac-xcode-and-c-beginning-1a52f43830c0